# importing mysql structures only or restore ignoring non-existing tables and columns?

Tags: mysql

I have 2 servers (1 for development, 1 for service)

I keep ADD/DELETE columns and CREATE/DELETE Indexes on my development server, so these 2 server have similar but different mysql data structures.

I know there's an option to expert structures only. (like –no-data)

Is there a way (except 3rd party software like mysqldiff.org) to import structure only to an existing data?

Alternativley, is there a way to import only data ignoring non-existing tables and colums? 
(I thought this may do the trick if I back-up data -> import structure -> restore the data.)

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same problem. I solved it like this:

Like you already mentioned:

back-up data -> import structure -> restore the data as follows

```
@DEVELOPEMENT (export structure only)<br/>
    **mysqldump -u user -p –d test > structure-only.sql**

@DEPLOYMENT (export data only)<br/>
    **mysqldump -u user -p -t -c test > data-only.sql**

@DEPLOYMENT (import structure only)<br/>
    **mysql -u user -p test < structure-only.sql**

@DEPLOYMENT (import data only)<br/>
    **mysql -u user -p test < data-only.sql**
```

The trick that made it work for me was the `-c` switch on the second export (this way full column names are used, and there are no `'column count'` errors when you import it back in the new structure).